# DJANGO: feinCMS missing mptt when trying to sync.db

Tags: django, django-mptt, feincms

I'm trying to setup an instance of FeinCMS to check it out. I've added the all the modules under `INSTALLED APPS` but when I run the command `python manage.py syncdb` I get the error `Import Error: No module named mptt`. What am I doing wrong?

My settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'feincms', 
    'mptt', 
    'feincms.module.page',
    'feincms.module.medialibrary'  
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the package?

```
> pip install django-mptt
```

I assume you're using a virtualenv?

Is your project running within the same Python env as the interpreter? If it is, a quick check would be:

```
> pip install yolk
> yolk -l  # see if the mptt package is available, if not:
> pip install django-mptt  # optionally use the --update flag
```

Still issues? Remove any `*.pyc` files and restart your server to make sure there's no import issues from previously removed files.

```
> find . -type f -name "*.pyc" | xargs rm
> ./manage.py runserver 8000
```

No good? Add a statement to your manage.py file right after your import statements:

```
# ...
import sys
print sys.path
```

Re-run the server to see if the mptt is missing from your path, if it is, check your site-packages folder and check the package's path.